# MySQL, two columns sharing the same join

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT
COALESCE (reports_straddons.employeeid, ldap_karen.uid) as uid,
COALESCE (reports_straddons.thomslocationcountrydescr, ldap_karen.thomslocationcountrydescr, 'NOVALUE') as thomslocationcountrydescr,
COALESCE (reports_straddons.thomslocationcity, ldap_karen.thomslocationcity, 'NOVALUE') as thomslocationcity, 
COALESCE (reports_straddons.regionname, ldap_karen.regionname) as regionname,
CONCAT(reports_jobroles.groupabrev, COALESCE(CONCAT(' - ', reports_straddons.sup_role),'')) as sa_title,
ldap_karen.created
FROM
reports_straddons
LEFT JOIN ldap_karen ON reports_straddons.employeeid = ldap_karen.uid 
LEFT JOIN reports_jobroles ON reports_straddons.roleid = reports_jobroles.nameid
```

Right now I am getting the user ID, country, city, region, but the group (compounded roles of roleid - sup_role) is a bit jacked up.  The group is a compound name that is made up of:

- roleid
- sup_role

We have one job role table that we are linking to with names like Manager, Engineer, Sales, AM, PM, whatever.

So an example would be PM - Engineer.  The roleid part I got working fine but not understanding what I have done wrong with the second part (and I have tried like 10 things which range from showing up anyone with a sup_role multiple times to only showing those with sup_roles - not everyone has both).  So I have a join that is used for two distinct fields and both of those just contain the IDs to the joining table for the same column.

So right now I am getting Engineer - 9, 9 being the ID for the sup_role when it should read Developer if grabbing that name from the table based on the sup_role.

**Note:**  I first logically used `LEFT JOIN reports_jobroles ON reports_straddons.sup_role = reports_jobroles.nameid` but alas this did not work at all.

Comment: I don't see a group anywhere

Comment: How is it "jacked up"? What are you getting back and what are you expecting to get back? There are no obvious errors in your SQL without that info.

Comment: @JoePhilllips - what do you mean by group?

Comment: @mkasberg - pretty much no matter what I can't get the second field to show anything but the ID.  I added more info - let me know if there is anything else I can add.  But I have tried an array of ways to show the sup_role and it either shows the ID of the sup_role or it shows the name from the roleid field - just duplicates.

Comment: @blankip What do YOU mean by group? "but the group is a bit jacked up"

Comment: @blankip I still don't understand what the problem is but you can probably fix it with a CASE statement

Comment: @JoePhilllips - sorry terminology is bad - Group = compounded role.  Will edit that.

Comment: Can you produce a simplified example at http://sqlfiddle.com/ and show us the current output and the expected output?

Comment: I still have no clue what that query has to do with your question. I see nothing in there that is a "compound name made up of roleid and sup_role"

Comment: @JoePhilllips - I have reports_jobroles.groupabrev, COALESCE(CONCAT(' - ', reports_straddons.sup_role).  The reports_straddons.sup_role should be reports_jobroles.groupabrev(2).  But I am having a hard time equating the sup_role to the reports_jobroles.groupabrev column because I have already used it for the roleid column.   Logically I thought I would LEFT JOIN reports_jobroles ON reports_straddons.sup_role = reports_jobroles.nameid

Comment: ^ That's the missing piece of info we needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand. The problem is you need to join to a table twice, but you're only joining it once. A simplified version of your problem would look like this:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE (reports_straddons.employeeid, ldap_karen.uid) as uid,
CONCAT(reports_jobroles.groupabrev, COALESCE(CONCAT(' - ', reports_straddons.sup_role),'')) as sa_title
FROM
reports_straddons
LEFT JOIN reports_jobroles ON reports_straddons.roleid = reports_jobroles.nameid
```

To fix it, you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE (reports_straddons.employeeid, ldap_karen.uid) as uid,
CONCAT(roles.groupabrev, COALESCE(CONCAT(' - ', suproles.groupabrev),'')) as sa_title
FROM
reports_straddons
LEFT JOIN reports_jobroles roles ON reports_straddons.roleid = roles.nameid
LEFT JOIN reports_jobroles suproles ON reports_straddons.sup_role = suproles.nameid
```

Notice how I'm joining to reports_jobroles twice, and naming it something different. I'm under the assumption that `sup_role` will join to the `nameid` field much like `roleid`.

Comment: Thank you.  Very frustrating I couldn't get that on my own.  I think you need to change the "=reports_jobroles" to "roles" and "suproles" and you are 100%.  It looks like 4-5 versions ago I was about the same but a similar typo through me down another dead end path.

Comment: Fixed. I wrote that without running it anywhere so I didn't have any syntax checking...